# Trouble with extension popup, jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

This is my first attempt at a chrome extension so bear with me. 
My intention is to have a popup that shows one of two icons, one if a specific script is loaded, and one icon if not. I have it working in the browser but am having trouble in the plugin. $ is not defined is showing, not sure if the manifest is the jquery issue or not. If you could look over what I've got so far I'd appreciate it.

Manifest

```
   {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Sandbox Notice",
  "description": "Sandbox notice",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js",
      "jquery.min.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {

      "matches": ["https://xxx.xxx.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "background.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Popup html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="background.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <img id="status" src="">
  </body>
</html>
```

background js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($('script[src="https://xxx.xxx.com/js/xxx.js"]').length > 0) {
        $("#status").attr("src","pro.png");
    } else {
        $("#status").attr("src","sb.png");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are mixing up two very different things: a popup and a background page.

Do not name your popup "background.js", its a popup so name it popup.js. this is what caused confusion to the other answer.

then in popup.html simply include your local jquery like you would include any other library before including popup.js

Comment: Thank you! Up and running now, I have some more reading to do on extensions but that was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you need to tell that your background that jquery is available in your `manifest` file.

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [

      "scripts/jquery.min.js", //change this to point to your location
        "scripts/background.js" // change this to point to your location
    ]
  }
```

Also the order is important,you need jquery before background.js is run.

Comment: I added that but still getting $ is not defined, hummm.

Comment: lol I hope so. I just have everything in the extension's root folder, jquery file too, so I'm not adding scripts/ to the manifest.

Comment: put jquery before background.js ,. as this impacts whcih gets loaded first. Also there is no guarantee which gets loaded so you might want to put like a timeout to see if jquery has been loaded.

Comment: good call on order but no change, I'll test a timeout and see.

Comment: no. the real issue is he should never name "background" what is NOT a background page but a popup page. do not do that. name it popup.js and include jquery in popup.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, renaming to popup and adding jquery in the html got it running.